# Write a custom hook that sets the current progress: React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I am having a progress bar which on click starts its progress from 60 to all the way upto 100. I am able to achieve this using settinterval and setting the corresponding state.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import ProgressBar from "./ProgressBar";

export default function App() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState({ status: 0, error: "" });
  const mockRef = useRef(60);

  const initiate = () => {
    const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      if (mockRef.current >= 100) {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        setFile((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          status: 100
        }));
      } else {
        setFile((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          status: mockRef.current
        }));
        mockRef.current = mockRef.current + 10;
      }
    }, 200);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" style={appStyles}>
      <button type="button" onClick={initiate}>
        Click Me!
      </button>
      <ProgressBar bgColor={"#DF8100"} progress={file.status} />
      {file.status === 100 && <span>Upload complete</span>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am using the ref to dymanically increment the progress by 10 and when its 100, I clear it and bring the message as `Upload Complete`. Code works just fine.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-react-progress-bar-forked-yfz9xb?file=/src/useProgress.jsx:0-436

Now I want the content inside of `initiate`to move it to a custom hooks that should take care of the setinterval functionality and set the object so that the functionality remains the same. May be this cutsom hook should take initial percentage as number and may be the state setter.

Any idea how I can write this custom hook.This is what my attempt looks like

```
import { useRef } from "react";

export const useProgress = (state, timer) => {
  const mockRef = useRef(timer);

  const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    if (mockRef.current >= 100) {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
      return {
        ...state,
        status: 100
      };
    } else {
      mockRef.current = mockRef.current + 10;
      return {
        ...state,
        status: mockRef.current
      };
    }
  }, 200);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have something working within a function component that you want to turn into a hook, it's often easier than one might think. Usually, you can copy the functioning code you have directly into the hook; make the hook accept anything it needs from outside that code as parameters; and return whatever the calling component will need from the hook as a return value (if there are multiple values, wrap them in an array [tuple] or object).

In your case, just copy everything prior to the `return` from your component into a hook, and have the hook return `file` and `initiate`:

```
export const useProgress = () => {
    const [file, setFile] = useState({ status: 0, error: "" });
    const mockRef = useRef(60);

    const initiate = () => {
        const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
            if (mockRef.current >= 100) {
                clearInterval(intervalID);
                setFile((prevState) => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    status: 100,
                }));
            } else {
                setFile((prevState) => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    status: mockRef.current,
                }));
                mockRef.current = mockRef.current + 10;
            }
        }, 200);
    };

    return [file, initiate];
};
```

Then `App` uses it like this:

```
export default function App() {
    const [file, initiate] = useProgress();

    return (
        <div className="App" style={appStyles}>
            <button type="button" onClick={initiate}>
                Click Me!
            </button>
            <ProgressBar bgColor={"#DF8100"} progress={file.status} />
            {file.status === 100 && <span>Upload complete</span>}
        </div>
    );
}
```

[Updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-react-progress-bar-forked-vddnzr?file=/src/useProgress.jsx)

Answer (score 1):

You can provide `updater` handler function and the `timer` start value as arguments which can change depending on where you use your custom hook is used.

This would also work:

```
import { useRef } from "react";

const useProgress = (updater, timer) => {
  const mockRef = useRef(timer);

  const initiate = () => {
    const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      if (mockRef.current >= 100) {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        updater((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          status: 100
        }));
      } else {
        mockRef.current = mockRef.current + 10;
        updater((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          status: mockRef.current
        }));
      }
    }, 200);
  };

  return initiate;
};

export default useProgress;
```

In your `App.jsx`

```
...
...
export default function App() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState({ status: 0, error: "" });
  const initiate = useProgress(setFile, 60);

  return (
    <div className="App" style={appStyles}>
      <button type="button" onClick={initiate}>
        Click Me!
      </button>
      <ProgressBar bgColor={"#DF8100"} progress={file.status} />
      {file.status === 100 && <span>Upload complete</span>}
    </div>
  );
}
...
```

Codesandbox Demo:

[image: Edit simple react progress bar (forked)]

If the state is an array then `fileIndex` can be passed into the custom hook:

[image: Edit simple react progress bar (forked)]

Comment: Thanks Amila, one small edit, If the state were  array `const [file, setFile] = useState([{ status: 0, error: "" }]);` then how would the setter look like

Comment: @lrr59, added another sandbox to the answer for that. please check!!

Comment: I guess you need to show multiple files getting downloaded with their progress. For that you can define another component using your custom hook and downloader jsx together.

Comment: The same is mentioned here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76137270/custom-hook-taking-external-parameters